# "Script Halted" error when trying to migrate DB in EntityFrameWork Core with NuGet console

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

My specs are: Win7 x64, VS 2019, Entity framework 5.0.2

I follow this tutorial on EntityFrameWork Core (EFC): https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-console-application.aspx

I have installed EFC, EFC.SQLServer, EFC.Tools. Now, following the tutorial I tried to create my database using command:

```
add-migration CreateSchoolDB
```

But when I try to execute it, it gives me "script halted" error without further explanation, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm sorry I rushed with my question before googling it, but my question is the duplicate of this one:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643426/add-migration-command-only-prompt-scripthalted][1]

The solution, apparently, is to instal the newest version of windows powershell, which also might require an update of Windows management framework. After this the migration was executed successfully.

p.s.: someone please mark this question as duplicate, as I have no privileges to do it, I believe.
[1]: [Add-Migration command only prompt "ScriptHalted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643426/add-migration-command-only-prompt-scripthalted)